# Enviar mensagem de uma aplicação java web para whatsapp

Tags: java, api, aplicação-web, whatsapp

Galera, gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de enviar mensagem de aplicação java web para o aplicativo whatsapp. Existe alguma classe ou api que possa ajudar?

Exemplo: a pessoa faz uma compra e quando essa comprar for efetuada, enviar uma mensagem para whatsapp da pessoa "compra efetuada com sucesso".

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130096/3635

Comment: Pena que se tornou fora de escopo. Seria muito bom saber...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo o Watsap precisaria conceder um API valida para este serviço, o que ainda não acontece.

Comment: Valeu parceiro, existe alguma outra "ferramenta" ou ideia, que possa usar a não ser via sms?

Comment: Para enviar para o número de celular o mais garantido é o SMS pois terá garantia que será entregue a mensagem. O aplicativo Telegram (https://telegram.org/) e o seu derivado brasileiro zap-zap possuem clientes para todos os tipos de plataforma e até cliente web. O telegram por ser opensource tem API aberta: https://core.telegram.org/api essa seria uma opção. Você teria que orientar o cliente a se cadastrar nestes aplicativos.

Comment: Existem servidores de SMS para esse tipo de serviço, mas tem custo.